# SAP SD serial numbers and post goods issue

Tags: sap-erp

To post goods issue even if there are serial numbers inserted which are already used.

It is possible to use it, or not possible?

If this is not possible, SAP ECC SD module should display an error message.

Please if you have any explication.

I use transaction `VL02N`.